# Renaming a ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC causing a compilation error. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, compiler-errors, viewmodel

I renamed one of my ViewModels. Upon doing so, VS Express 2013 for Web asked me if I want it to change the name throughout my project and of course I said yes...

Well, now when I visit the page that uses that particular ViewModel I am given the following compilation error:

> **Compiler Error Message:** CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'OldNameViewModel' does not exist in the namespace
>   'MyProject.ViewModels' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

It shows me the following lines of code...

```
Line 28:     
Line 29:     
Line 30:     public class _Page_Views_Inventory_Create_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MyProject.ViewModels.OldNameViewModel> {
Line 31:         
Line 32: #line hidden
```

...and it gives me a path to the file where this code is located:

> **Source File:** c:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\d4024d39\1941e695\App_Web_create.cshtml.7f862902.aox9w9wr.0.cs

I went there and changed the `<MyProject.ViewModels.OldNameViewModel>` bit to `<MyProject.ViewModels.NewNameViewModel>` and saved...

I refreshed the page, same problem. I rebuilt, same problem. I deleted the entire "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory, same problem. I deleted the directory, closed IIS Express, closed VS, and then reopened, rebuilt, etc.—same problem: it keeps replacing the file with a new file using the `OldNameViewModel`.

Is this normal or has something funky happened? Either way, how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: in my experience having vs rename the variable for you only renames the code.  The views are left untouched.  I would do a solution search for the old name and replace wherever you find it

Comment: have you checked the corresponding view (Create.cshtml ?) to see if its @model directive is correct ?

Comment: Wow.. I figured something like the View's @model would be something VS would change for me.. so much so that I never checked it. I changed it now and everything is working. Thanks!